# Using orderBy with ngOptions "select as label for (key , value) in object" pattern

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-orderby

How do you use an `orderBy` with on a `<select></select>` in Angular 1.4.8 that is formatted with the following pattern?

`select` as `label` for (`key` , `value`) in `object`

This is what's currently in the ngOptions:

```
v.linkFieldName as v.linkFieldLabel for (k,v) in question.fieldLink.object2FieldList[question.Link_Object__c]
```

My goal is to put the contents of the select list in alphabetical order when you view them.

Comment: `orderBy` only works on arrays. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: So if I want that list to be alphabetized, then I would have to change the service that populated so that it sends an array to the <select> instead of an object, correct?

Comment: Right. Either that or order it before you use it in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using HTML and `ngRepeat` instead of `ngOptions`. For example something like this:

```
<select ng-model="myvVal">
  <option 
      ng-repeat="
          (k,v) in question.fieldLink.object2FieldList[question.Link_Object__c] 
          | orderBy:something" 
      value="v.linkFieldName">{{v.linkFieldLabel}}</option>
</select>
```